# workspace always open same file

Tags: visual-studio-code

It's my first day using VS Code and HTML and I did something that I don't know how to fix.
When I start work on VS Code I could open multiple tabs and when I clicked <kbd>F5</kbd> the specific tab I was on it - was run.
Now:
it always runs the same tab (even if I removed it from workspace).

** when I click on status bar (in bottom) it opens a small debug window and I see there the name of the same file that always opens.
If I click on the settings icon and it seems that it always directs me to the same file. I want change it so it will direct me to the current open tab.

I'm pretty sure my description is not enough (notice me for more details please). Anyway you can see in the image that story.html file always open no matter which file I try to run.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by changing the file directory into global directory which indicate to the current file.

```
${workspaceFolder} - indicate to current folder.
${file} - indicate to current file.
```